# Auto convert GMT to BST during daylight savings

Tags: c#

I am currently converting the current system time to UK time (GMT).

```
DateTime currentSystemTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
TimeZoneInfo timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GMT Standard Time");
DateTime currentUKTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(currentSystemTime, timeZoneInfo);
```

But it seems UK uses BST for months Mar to Oct and GMT for the rest of the year. How can I handle this in my code to use BST automatically during daylight savings and GMT during not daylight savings?

Thanks,
Souvik

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe this is already automatically handled by the DateTime object when you provide the time zone info but it is better for you to use the method **ConvertTimeFromUtc**.

You can check it by running this code, which converts some UTC dates to GMT date times:

```
Dim tzi As TimeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GMT Standard Time")
Dim dt1 As DateTime = DateTime.Parse("01/01/2015 8:00")
Dim dt2 As DateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(dt1, tzi)

Dim dt3 As DateTime = DateTime.Parse("06/06/2015 8:00")
Dim dt4 As DateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(dt3, tzi)

Assert.IsFalse(dt2.IsDaylightSavingTime)  //January is not saving daylight
Assert.IsTrue(dt4.IsDaylightSavingTime)  //June is

dt2.ToString()  //This returns "01/01/2015 08:00:00"
dt4.ToString() //This returns "06/06/2015 09:00:00"
```

Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973825.aspx#datetime_topic6

Comment: So will this work in sync with the BST? I have poor knowledge on time zones.

Comment: If I understood well what you need yes: providing that you are converting from UTC, if you use GMT as the local destination time zone, it will handle correctly the 1 hour daylight saving change in summer.